# When do I use pointers in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

Ive been programming Qt for a while now and I am wondering what the difference is between these two cases:

case1:

header:

```
QPushButton * button;
```

source file:

```
button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setText("Button");
button->resize(100,100);
```

and

case2:

header:

```
QPushButton button;
```

source:

```
button.setParent(this);
button.setText("Button");
button.resize(100,100);
```

Both produce a button, but when should I use the former and when the latter case? And what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Anycorn actually the QtCreator uses case 1 for child widgets

Comment: @Anycorn "the first case you will have to manually delete the pointer via delete." No.

Comment: @Jefffrey I see, the parent takes ownership of the child? I ll delete my comment, it is wong

Comment: The proper usage of pointers in Qt is distinctly different from the proper usage of pointers in modern C++, so I suggested a title change in an edit. Though they (pointers in C++ and pointers in C++ with Qt) both function the same (they are still both C++ pointers), they are used differently.

Comment: You usually don't have a choice, as `designer` will create an `.ui` file for you.

Comment: The second case crashes and is wrong!

Comment: @user1095108 "*You usually don't have a choice, as designer will create an .ui file for you*" - in almost every Qt program I write (even simple ones), I use a mixture of .ui and manually created widgets, so manually creating widgets isn't unusual. I often need to dynamically create widgets for some part or another of my interface. His second case definitely crashed though! =P

Comment: @user1095108 Why would the second case crash?

Comment: @thuga Because of automatic deletion of children by their `QObject` parent, but the widget possibly resides on the stack and was not allocated by `new` anyway.

Comment: @user1095108 According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) it should be safe.

Comment: @thuga Could be, but the page also says it could go wrong. I've experienced crashes because I did it wrongly sometimes. The idea is that your widget needs to be destroyed before the parent widget. If you mess up, the app will crash. I've messed up several times, that's why I don't do it anymore :)

Comment: @user1095108 I'm not saying it's the right thing to do. I'm just saying case 2 shouldn't cause a crash. If done as it's stated in case 2, the `QPushButton` object should be destroyed before its parent. This can be tested by connecting the [destroyed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#destroyed) signals of the `QPushButton` and its parent to a slot and see which one will fire first.

Comment: @thuga it is probably ok in this case, yeah, as `this` would not exist if parent were created before the `QPushButton`. I've equated `QObject`s on the stack to crashes, although this is not absolutely true.

Comment: @Anycorn Please don't delete your comments in the future.  For those of us new to qt, reading through your misunderstandings can be a helpful learning tool!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference between the first and second case is that when you use pointers and the `new` statement to allocate the button, the memory for the button is allocated in the free store (heap). In the second statement the memory is allocated on the stack.

There are two reasons why you would rather allocate memory in the free store than the stack.

1. The stack is of limited size and if you blow your stack budget your program will crash with a stack overflow. One can allocate much more memory in the free store and if a memory allocation fails, all that normally happens is that a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown.
2. Allocation on the stack is strictly last in first out (LIFO) which means that your button cannot exist for longer than the code block (whats between the `{...}` ) that allocated the memory. When memory is allocated in the free store, you as the programmer have full control of the time that the memory remains valid (although carelessness can cause memory leaks)

In your case, if the button just needs to exist for the duration of the calling function, you will probably be ok allocating the button on the stack; if the button needs to be valid for much longer stick to the free store

Answer (score 7):

Qt memory management works with hierarchies of objects, when parent object deletes child objects automatically on destroying. This is why Qt programs always use pointers in similar cases.

Memory Management with Qt:

Qt maintains hierarchies of objects. For widgets (visible elements) these hierarchies represent the stacking order of the widgets themselves, for non-widgets they merely express "ownership" of objects. Qt deletes child objects together with their parent object.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you are dynamically allocating the button (which means that it will be destroyed when the parent is destroyed). In the second case the button will disappear when the code block ends (meaning it goes out of scope).

Use the first when you want to `QObject`, you are referring to, to last more than just the block in which it is created.

In the context of the class you are referring to (assuming the `button` is a member variable in both cases) it doesn't make much difference.

Also you may want to use pointers when using polymorphism.

Comment: How is polymorphism relevant or affected either way? Polymorphism doesn't care about how the object was originally allocated. One can form a reference or pointer to a stack-allocated object to store/pass it polymorphically. Mode of allocation is orthogonal to mode of referring.

Answer (score 1):

An useful specific usage: when posting custom events, carrying detailed data, for instance:

```
/** support SWI... prolog_edit:edit_source(File) */
struct reqEditSource : public QEvent {
    QString file;
    QByteArray geometry;
    reqEditSource(QString file, QByteArray geometry = QByteArray())
        : QEvent(Type(User+1)), file(file), geometry(geometry) {}
};
```

you can 'fire and forget' them:

```
qApp->postEvent(this, new reqEditSource(files[i], p.value(k).toByteArray()));
```

The event will be deleted after its delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Many functions in Qt that take an object as argument, actually take a pointer to an object. That's because passing an object "by value" would actually create a copy of the object (via copy constructor) and pass that copy! Creating a new copy of the object has a lot of overhead. At the same time, passing the object "by reference", i.e. as a pointer, will just pass a 32-Bit memory address, which is a very lightweight operation.